# How can I create multiple logical conditions using Zapier plugin for Gravity Forms in a WordPress web site?

Tags: wordpress, zapier, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

My web site is running on WordPress, and I'm using Gravity Forms and Zapier plugins. As it is now, Zapier only allows for a single logical condition to check for to see if it should run a connected zap.

How do you create conditional statements without using the UI? Is there a hook and event that I could modify to let me achieve this? Do I just need a custom plugin?

In need to run the Zap with multiple conditional statements. I cannot put the logic on the Zapier side, because an 3rd party created the zap hook, and I can't edit the conditional logic there.

If you look at this image of the Gravity Forms/Zapier interface on the plugin, there is no additional + key at the end to add more conditional statements.
[image: Normally - there'd be a + button to add multiple conditional statements, but not for Zapier!]

I've found some information on the GravityForms forum that said they were planning on building this functionality back in 2019, but as of yet, it has not been implemented in the plugin. It has been implemented in their Zapier interface, but again, because the zap we are using was created by a 3rd party, we cannot edit their zap.

Answer (score 0):

The latest Zapier update for Gravity Forms (ver 4.0) includes multi-conditional statements.